# Android sample application

Tags: android

I just started working with Android apps and was trying few sample programs. I noticed an issue with the main.xml file. It happened twice today, I added few new layout views in main.xml (Using Layout and XML both), as soon as I made a modification and tried running the program, the R.java class would throw an error, also a new file called main.out.xml is getting created automatically. On top of this, when I am trying to "clean" the project, it deletes the R.java file altogether. Why is it acting this way?

Comment: Eclipse is a piece of crap. You're better off with a proper IDE like IntelliJ. After using Eclipse for 8 years, I switched to IntelliJ IDEA a year ago, which is not free but worth the dollars. Eclipse has a lot of these bugs you mentioned. It's very unreliable in that regard. Sometimes clean doesn't help but only a restart of the IDE, really annoying and inefficient.

Comment: @Mathias, thanks for the suggestion. How about RAD? I know its built on top of Eclipse, but is it any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the eclipse IDE relating to android development. I had the same problem when I first started. You need to make sure that the file that is currently being edited (i.e. active in the editor) is a java source file when you try to run the project. If any other file is active, such as your main.xml file then it ends up creating this main.out.xml that is a garbage file. To fix, just delete the garbage main.out.xml and make sure a java file is active and hit run and you are back to normal.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect solution. Worked liked a charm. There is no permanent fix for this? Are there any other traps I need to watch out for?

Comment: Thats the only really goofy thing that I have noticed. I have been unable to find a solution other then this work around.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting that tmp file and re-cleaning the project

Comment: What exactly causes this problem?

Comment: Well it did remove the error notification, but now as soon as I try to run the program, its creating the same main.out.xml and then program fails saying  Error parsing XML: no element found